# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty}E\left(\frac{|\overline X_n|}{|\overline X_n| + 1}\right)^2$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2 > 0$. Compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty}E\left(\frac{|\overline X_n|}{|\overline X_n| + 1}\right)^2$$

Please help, I've tried expansion and Markov's theorem. It's not working.

Comment: Are you sure? I think $\overline X_n=\frac1n(X_1+\ldots+X_n)\to EX_i=0$ a.s. as $n\to\infty$, so the limit should be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the numerator and the denominator of the fraction by $n$. By SLLN you see that the ratio tends to $1$. Also, the fraction is bounded by $1$. Hence, by DCT we see that the limit is $1$.